# What is the returned result from a SELECT MAX() when table is empty in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, select, return-value, max

I have a table for users payments. I need to specify a receipt code for each transaction, so I need to know what was the last one? And if there is not previous receipt, I want to add the first one with **1000** and other reciepts must be incremental like **1001, 1002, ...**
For this, I wrote this code:

```
$receipt = '1000';
$query_receipt = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(receipt) FROM tbl_payments");
$max = mysql_result($query_receipt,0);
if ($max != '0' || $max != '')
{
    $receipt = mysql_result($query_receipt,0) + 1;
}
```

It works fine when I have a record in the table. But it returns **1** when table is empty. How can I solve this problem? I need to know the returned value from a `SELECT MAX() ...` even if table be empty.

Comment: If you need a value that increases for each added row, you should use an auto-increment column instead of trying to generate ids yourself.

Comment: What you need exactly? You donot expect 1. Then what is your expected output when table is empty ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can achive this by using `IFNULL` as:

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(receipt), 1000) FROM tbl_payments;
```

Comment: Actually, re-reading the question, I think the OP wants to insert a row if there isn't one already there with the base value of 1000. I don't think this can be done with a single query, but your SQL Kung Fu is better than mine :)

Answer (score 3):

You get a null value:

```
mysql> create table noRows (id int(3));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select max(id) from noRows;
+---------+
| max(id) |
+---------+
|    NULL |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can however use a coalesce to get what you need:

```
mysql> select coalesce(max(id),1) from noRows;
+---------------------+
| coalesce(max(id),1) |
+---------------------+
|                   1 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Edit: If you are looking to check it the user already has one and if not, to insert a new row, it can't be done with a single query as far as I know, but the following should work:

```
$receipt = 1000;
$query_receipt = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(receipt) FROM tbl_payments");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_receipt);
if($num_rows>0)
{
    // Assumes $ID to be some unique field used to identify your customer stored in field ID.
    $sql="insert into tbl_payments (ID, receipt) values ($ID, $receipt)";
    mysql_result($sql)
}
else
{
    // Do stuff here to get the receipt from the first resultset.
}
```

On that note, you might want to consider moving away from the old deprecated `mysql_*` functions and move to [PDO](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. It is much safer and has a lot more features.

Comment: Impressive Man, I have also stuck in this. Tried so much then try STO and here I am... Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also recommend, to use an auto_increment value, and determine your current receipt number by the insert_id. Simply execute your `INSERT`-Query and afterwards use for example [mysqli_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get the id of your inserted payment.

If you want to start with a value of 1000, you can change the start value of your auto increment column. I found this to set up auto increment to start with 1000

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work as your insert statement.  No need to use PHP to run two queries as above, you can do the same outcome direct in MYSQL.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_payments (receipt)
VALUES 
(
(SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(p.receipt) IS NULL THEN 1000 ELSE MAX(p.receipt)+1 END AS receipt 
    FROM tbl_payments p ORDER BY p.receipt DESC LIMIT 1)
)
```